# wagtailmenus: TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/wagtailmenus/mainmenu/edit/2/

Tags: wagtail

The error occurs when i want to start "Settings/MainMenu" in the Wagtail admin.
The Template "_editor_css.html" doesn't exist in installation files of wagtailmenus or wagtail. What I'm missing?

> wagtail=4.0.2 wagtailmenus=3.1.2 Django=4.1.2

```
wagtailadmin/pages/_editor_css.html
1   {% extends "modeladmin/create.html" %}
2   
3   {% block extra_css %}
4       {% include "wagtailadmin/pages/_editor_css.html" %}
5       {{ edit_handler.form.media.css }}
6       {{ view.media.css }}
7   {% endblock %}
8   
9   {% block extra_js %}
10      {% include "wagtailadmin/pages/_editor_js.html" %}
11      {{ edit_handler.form.media.js }}
12      {{ edit_handler.html_declarations }}
13      {{ view.media.js }}
14  {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of writing, [wagtailmenus has not yet been updated with support for Wagtail 4.0](https://github.com/jazzband/wagtailmenus/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

(Wagtailmenus overrides Wagtail's internal `_editor_css.html` include, which has been removed in Wagtail 4.0.)